# Python Jupyter Notebook: Text format in the Markdown cell

Tags: python-3.x, markdown, jupyter-notebook

I am using Python 3.4 kernel on Jupyter Notebook. I noticed some inconsistent behaviors in the Markdown cell. For example, if I have

```
## Students
### John
### Mary
```

Sometimes, it shows like below with different font size:

```
Student

John
Mary
```

But sometimes it has number in front of it:

```
1 Student

1.1 John
1.2 Mary
```

Why does this happen and how can I control it? Thanks!